# Difference between next(context) vs await next.Invoke(context) in .net core middleware creation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-5, asp.net-core-middleware

As per my understanding, we need to use the next(context) to call the next request delegate/middleware. I have gone through multiple online resources, but have not found an exact difference between **next(context) and next.Invoke(context)**.

I want to use next(context) in place of next.Invoke(context) in existing code written by another person based on my learning. If I am using next() instead of next.Invoke(context), everything is working fine.  I want to know if it will impact anything or there is any difference between these two calls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`next` is a `RequestDelegate` in this context, hence there is no functional difference between `next(context)` and `next.Invoke(context)`. `next(context)` will be translated to `next.Invoke(context)`.

Please note that you'll need to await `next(context)` in the same situations as with `next.Invoke(context)`.

More info on custom middleware: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write?view=aspnetcore-5.0